# What happened to Saul's right hand man Huell?

Tags: breaking-bad

In the last season of Breaking Bad, Hank and Gomez put Saul's right-hand man Huell in their custody and instructed him not to leave until they said so. A few episodes later Hank and Gomez are killed and since this was a secret mission, no one else would have known about it.

What happened to Huell after all the apocalypse?

Comment: This seems to be an opinion-based or speculation question and not really in the scope of the stack. There is no canon answer to be had. Opinion: he got hungry and left. It's unreasonable to assume he stayed sitting in the chair and starved to death.

Comment: So do you think I should close this question ? It just came to my mind and I thought of asking it here.

Comment: There is no "real" answer as it isn't addressed on the show. It's a question I thought about, but does not seem to have an answer beyond guessing. 

The dude's fat. He got hungry. What other answer could there be? The room wasn't paid for enough in advance and he got kicked out? I'm leaning more towards hungry.

Comment: I have removed the "speculative" language from the question. It doesn't really change the answer of "we don't know," but it does help to reduce the possibility for wild speculative answers. I hope.

Comment: I think he would be **reasonably** OK.

Comment: I've amended *Manishearth*'s answer by official quotes from the show's creators that support his explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

Whilst there is no definitive answer to this, I imagine sooner or later he just got on with his life...

Also, [for your pleasure...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oP_4z4IoYHs)

Answer (score 13):

> A few episodes later Hank and Gomez are killed and since this was a secret mission, no one else would have known about it.

Nope. Remember, there was another DEA officer (or similar) taking care of Huell. He didn't know about the case, but he did know that Hank and Gomez had kept Huell there.

I think it's pretty safe to say that Hank used official channels to get the safehouse setup. IIRC, these channels are designed in a manner such that there is a trail, but one that is very hard to track down (well, there *has* to be a trail, since government resources are being used up).

I bet that the death of Hank/Gomez is noticed by those in charge of the protection, and sooner or later a connection with the Heisenberg case is made. In which case the DEA would determine why Huell was kept in a safehouse, and take him into their custody (or free him) if they feel it prudent.

---

This is in fact reinforced by series creator Vince Gilligan himself in his book about *Breaking Bad*, as quoted in [this entertainment weekly article](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/05/14/breaking-bad-huell-what-happened-vince-gilligan?utm_source=huffingtonpost.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=pubexchange_article):

> **Is Huell still waiting for someone to come back for him?**
>   Yes, sadly he’s waiting morosely on that sofa, looking like a lost puppy… [Laughs] No. It’s likely that Agent Van Oster keeps in touch with DEA headquarters. So when he learns Gomez and Hank have gone missing, he would in short order tell his superiors what they were up to. Within a matter of hours, really not that many in story time, Huell will be taken back to HQ. They’ll question him, find out what he knows—which isn’t much—and he’ll be let out on the street. Right now, he’s doing what Huell does best, whatever that is. He’s out and about as a free man.

Comment: I took the liberty to add Vince Gilligan's very own explanation to your answer instead of as a separate answer, since it is pretty much exactly the same as yours, only from the official authority.

Answer (score 3):

#### He walked free.

In Season 6 Episode 11 of *Better Call Saul*, appropriately titled "Breaking Bad", Francesca told Jimmy (Saul) that Huell "walked" (was free from custody).

Related dialogue:

> **Jimmy:** All right, how about Huell?
> **Francesca:** Huell. [*sighs*] I guess back home in New Orleans.
> DEA held him under false pretenses or something, so last I heard, he walked.

The scene where the above dialogue took place was set after the events of *Breaking Bad*, after Walter White had died, and after Jimmy had been given a new identity, "Gene Takovic", by the Disappearer ("vacuum cleaner repairman"). Jimmy called Francesca on a payphone to ask for updates on the current situation.